# Line following in ROS

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I was just wondering if there is any demo/tutorial on line following for ROS.
I have a Turtlebot and I would like to mount a webcam on it and let it follow a line.

I found some [line following algorithm](https://github.com/robotictang/eddiebot_line_follower) for the [Eddiebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eddiebot), which is somewhat similar to Turtlebot. I am trying to make it work with the Turtlebot. Any hints and help are welcomed.

Being a rookie in ROS I don't know how to make this work in ROS and Turtlebot. Can anyone please help me here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58443/line-following-in-ros/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2013-04-02**:
Maybe.. need to extract the line from image. If u have a camera model, u are able to get the relative coordinates of the line respect to your robot. feed it into global planner... Or u do not have a camera model, you can build a PID controller, make sure the line is perpendicular in the near end..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found another solution for Turtlebot with line tracking and collision detection. Here you can see a video in action: [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWnQY2uLXA0) and the code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/radoi90/Turtlebot-track.git):
However, this was written for the original Turtlebot, and I
if you want to use it on Turtlebot 2 it needs the following adjustments: the program sends the move commands to a false topic, thus it needs to be changed to the right one: /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop at line 5 in Movement.cpp.

---

Originally posted by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) with karma: 248 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-08-24**:
I want to build a similar project but i don't have a turtlebot. I will build a robot platform on my own. Can you pls tell me what are all the hardware does this project(package) utilizes. so that i will build a custom robot including the required hardware.